# I haven't been vs I wasn't

Tags: grammar

Why it is true to say "I haven't been here before, but It looks great." I don't understand it because I was there and "I haven't been here before" doesn't have any connections to present now does it?
Wouldn't it be better, if I say "I wasn't here before.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The quoted statement "I haven't been here before, but It looks great." is grammatically correct, and I'm not sure what the statement "I was there and it doesn't have any connections to present now." is - should that be in the quote?

Comment: Sorry. I have just edited it.

Comment: My comment still applies. The quoted sentence seems to be correct (except for capitalization of "It". It's not clear what you're talking about in your second sentence.

Comment: I tried to make it clearer.

Comment: OK, I think I get what you're asking. See my answer below.

Comment: This needs moving to ELL!

Answer (score -1):

I think I understand what you're asking based on your title. It's equally correct to say "I haven't been here before..." and "I wasn't here before..."

They have slightly different connotations, in that "wasn't here before" might be specific to a the single time you were near that place last, but they're more-or-less equivalent.

As an example, if you were in Chicago, IL, USA for the first time, you might say "I haven't been here before...". The word "before" implies "before now".

If you were currently visiting Chicago for the first time, but you had been in Illinois (or the USA) on some previous occasion, but didn't go to Chicago, you might say "I wasn't here before...". In that case, the root word "was" slightly changes the meaning of "before", which could mean "before now" or "the opportunity I had before now".